# Webpack3 don't recompile vendor bundle if only application code is changed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-3

Currently I am utilizing the CommonsChunkPlugin to separate my vendor bundle (/node_modules/), from my main application bundle.  This works great.

I was originally hoping this would mean that if a change is made to my application code, a 're-packing' would be faster as the vendor bundle is separate and would not re-pack (and rarely changing).

It looks like a change to my application code also creates a new vendor bundle (when I am using watch mode or the dev server).  Is there a way to configure things to be smart and detect only application bundle changes were made and not re-pack the vendor bundle?

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the configuration in [here](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-commons-chunk). Try it out and see if thats what you intend to achieve.

Honestly, there is not much i had to think through. Its very well documented [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#extracting-boilerplate).